# System.Drawing is not in add reference

Tags: c#

To write a Winphone app, I need to use using System.Drawing, and I found on Internet I should first add reference, it is not in the .NET list, what should I do?

It is Visual studio 2010.

In one solution, it says .NET 4.0 and above supports this, where should I check the version information?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use System.Drawing on a phone, it is only available in desktop apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to write a *Windows Phone* application. You're not using .NET 4. It's not clear which *version* of Windows Phone you're using, but I don't think any of them support `System.Drawing`.

You need to find the API docs for the version of Windows Phone you're developing for, and refer to those docs instead.

For example, [here's the Windows Phone 8 API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626516%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).